# How to configure ShrewSoft VPN for Cisco VPN with Token Code?

Tags: windows-8, vpn

I am trying to get ShrewSoft VPN to work with a Cisco VPN connection that requires a next token code.

With Cisco VPN or NPC Secure Client these are the steps I would take:

1. List item
2. Import .pcf file
3. Connect and enter username/password
4. Token code is emailed to me
5. Enter token code into client
6. Connected

With ShrewSoft I cannot figure out what option will have it prompt me for the next token code.  It does get emailed to me but I never have the chance to enter it.  Is this a supported feature of ShrewSoft?

The reason why I'm trying to use ShrewSoft?
- Cisco VPN does not run on my Samsung ATIV Smart PC (runs full Windows 8 not RT)
- NPC Secure Client runs great but costs $144, steep for just occasional use tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Shrewsoft doesn't give you the next token code.  The RSA soft token app should do this.  But when it comes to setting up a PIN through work, I've never been successful with Shrewsoft (and honestly, I couldn't get through a "we don't support that" conversation with people who ask me to do what I do with Cisco).

If you're connecting through work, they should be able to set a PIN for you (at least mine did for me).  With that, you should be able to connect by entering the PIN in your RSA token app and then pasting that 6 digit code into Shrewsoft.  Or at least that's how I used to do it until they upgraded to AnyConnect from Cisco which works even with 1709.